# How do you calculate the energy output if you know the volts, amps and time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electric-circuits

How do you calculate the energy output if you know the volts, amps and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P=IV$ where, $P$ is power, $V$ is voltage, and $I$ is current in amps.

$E=Pt$ where $E$ is energy and $t$ is time.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that voltage and current are either DC or in phase. Otherwise you really need to integrate over time: $E=\int{I(t)V(t)dt}$